# How i can run a default browser from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, php

I create a PHP server instance and I would like to run browser automatically with running `run.bat`

Bat file content:

```
"php/php.exe" -S localhost:81 -t dokuwiki
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write folowing...

```
start website_address
```